# UNIQUE constraint for Neo4j relationship property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints

I know how to create an index on the relationship property in Neo4j:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR ()-[r:CONTAINS]-() ON (r.uuid)
```

but how to add `UNIQUE` constraint to `r.uuid` there?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) this is enabled for enterprise edition only.

Comment: But you get Enterprise edition on AuraDB and Sandbox and Desktop too.  But unique relationship constraints don't exist yet only existence constraints.

Comment: Thanks, closer to the release, I'll contact Neo4j AuraDB team to move to the managed cloud solution. Right now, I run everything within a local docker container for Neo4j Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: According to Michael Hunger from neo4j and [stdob--](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989460/stdob), this is not yet possible.

**

I can't check it, since I don't have the Enterprise edition,

but If I combine the [docs example for Unique node property constraints](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/examples/#administration-constraints-prop-exist-rels):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOR (book:Book) REQUIRE book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

With the docs example for Relationship property existence constraints:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOR ()-[like:LIKED]-() REQUIRE like.day IS NOT NULL
```

I can only assume that when it is possible, its syntax will be:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOR ()-[r:CONTAINS]-() REQUIRE r.uuid IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Unfortunately no: `'IS UNIQUE' does not allow relationship patterns`